# A bad practice regarding java enum

Tags: java, enums

This question is about a certain bad programming practice.
I am looking for some good article that explains about it and why it's bad.
Unfortunately, I don't know any name or jargon for this practice.
So I will try to describe it instead and ask you to tell me how it's called and maybe refer me to a good article on the subject.

Suppose we have some enum:

```
public enum Day
{
    SUNDAY, MONDAY, ...
}
```

Next, suppose that the server-side programmer attaches a numeric id to each day.
The correct thing to do, of course, is to map each `Day` to an `Integer` using an `EnumMap`, which is defined and used only within the server-side code.
Instead, he messes up the common code and adds a `getId()` method:

```
public enum Day
{
    SUNDAY {public int getId() {return 100;}},
    MONDAY {public int getId() {return 101;}},
    ...;

    public abstract int getId();
}
```

Next, the GUI programmer wants to attach a string to each day, so he adds his own stuff:

```
public enum Day
{
    SUNDAY {
        public int getId() {return 100;}
        public String getName() {return "sunday";}
    },
    MONDAY {
        public int getId() {return 101;};
        public String getName() {return monday";}
    },
    ...;

    public abstract int getId();
    public abstract String getName();
}
```

You get the point...

How do you call this thing?
Know any good article about it?

Comment: The correct way would be `Enum.ordinal()` instead of EnumMap.

Comment: I don't know if there is a special name for it. Inconsistent is probably the best term. If you utilize an enum method and follow the constructor paradigm, you guarantee that the result will be there.

Comment: @VeriTi: I beg to differ. Have you read what the [Enum API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) has to say about use of `ordinal()`? They beg to differ as well.

Comment: @VeriTi The id is not necessarily the ordinal. I mapped sunday to 0 and monday to 1 just by default.

Comment: @roel I have changed your questions title. That way it is more meaningful. Revert the change if you deem it invalid.

Comment: @Dariusz i reverted the change because it does not reflect what i wanted to ask. i didn't ask what's the right way to map enums to values. I just want to know if there is some conventional name for  the thing i described.

Comment: @roel I'm not sure getting stack overflow to agree with you that your collegue is wrong is exactly on topic. How to do it correctly on the other hand is

Comment: @RichardTingle i'm not trying to convince anyone here that my colleague is wrong. i was just asking what's the name, if any, of this thing that i described (apparently, it has no name), and i changed the title to reflect my original question. the other question, namely, how to do it correctly, is certainly worth a discussion (which is what this discussion turned into), but it's not what i asked.

Answer (score 7):

I wouldn't see why this is bad, other than it's more verbose than it should be. You could replace that with:

```
public enum Day {
    SUNDAY(0, "sunday"),
    MONDAY(1, "monday"),
    TUESDAY(2, "tuesday"),
    WEDNESDAY(3, "wednesday"),
    THURSDAY(4, "thursday"),
    FRIDAY(5, "friday"),
    SATURDAY(6, "saturday");

    private final int mIndex;
    private final String mName;

    Day (int index, String name) {
        mIndex = index;
        mName = name;
    }

    public int getIndex () {
        return mIndex;
    }

    public String getName () {
        return mName;
    }

    public static Day fromIndex (int index) {
        if (index < 0 || index > 6) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(index + " is not a valid day index.");
        }

        Day result = null;

        for (Day day : values()) {
            if (day.mIndex == index) {
                result = day;
                break;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

I use this pattern frequently for corralling data from a web service that's returned as an integer. It's certainly better practice than using `Day.ordinal()`, as then the order of definition within your enum becomes important, and requires the indices to be sequential.

Comment: You could use an array to look up `fromIndex` even if you don't want to use `values()` directly you could cache a re-built `Day[]`

Comment: Note: `getIndex()` == `ordinal()` as in they will both return the same thing. Also, for your `fromIndex(int)`, why not just do `Day.values()[index]`?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I went down that road at one point, then I went through and ran some performance tests and realized that the difference was ridiculously negligible, so for clarity, I just use `values()` now.

Comment: @JoshM Only in this contrived example. That does not necessarily have to be the case. If for some reason the data from the web service returned values such as `[15, 32, 8, 22]` (non-sequential), then ordinal comparison would no longer work.

Comment: I don't see how creating a copy of an array and iterating over it could be much the same as an array lookup of a cached array.  One is O(N) and the other O(1)

Comment: @kcoppock Unless you create an array `new Day[33]` and look that up by index.

Comment: Yes, but you're talking nanoseconds here. Unless you're writing performance-critical code, the time saved for this operation is not worth the added complexity of copying the list into an array.

Comment: I'm not saying that it's bad practice to copy and cache an array, it's that I just do not believe that it's necessary.

Comment: @kcoppock I don't entirely rule out this practice, but in my example it is bad. The reason I consider it bad, is because it violates the _separation of concerns_ principle. `Day` is infrastructure code, whereas `getId()` is server-side code, and `getName()` is GUI code. By inserting special purpose code into the general purpose class, you turn a short and simple class into big and unreadable one.

Comment: @PeterLawrey So I ran through and did a 1,000,000 pass run (not super-scientific) using `values()` vs caching the array. Using values() took 3,996 ms (~3 ns each), whereas the cached version took only 1,605 ms (~1 ns each). So for performance critical code, I absolutely agree you should cache the array, and frankly it certainly doesn't hurt anything to do it all the time. For something that's only called infrequently though, I just wasn't super concerned about a couple of nanoseconds.

Comment: @roel I see. So your concern is just that the name code doesn't belong there. I could see that being a valid concern, and could definitely get out of hand.

Comment: I am being pedantic here. The `return null` at the end can not happen. It seems inaproppriate, especially with the check and thrown exception at the beginning. For clarity, I would consider going for `Day result = null; result=day; break; return result`. Or throw the exception after iteration if no result has been found.

Comment: @Dariusz Heh, totally true. I didn't want to throw the exception *afterwards*, as there's no point iterating through the list if you know you won't get a result. I've edited the comment to rearrange it as you suggested -- I think you're right that it's clearer.